# Dart/Flutter Debug Console Issue on Visual Studio Code

Tags: flutter, dart, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to `print('hi')` inside Visual Studio Code's Debug Console using Dart/Flutter.

Whenever I perform a restart, it works just fine. As you can see in the debug console it prints: `I/flutter: hi`

Performing a restart takes up to one minute of loading time. This isn't very ideal.

Ideally I would prefer that `print()` displays on the console whenever I perform a hot reload (as this only a takes a few seconds).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running a flutter app. That's quite expensive even if your "app" is only a print. Depending on your machine, reloading or even restarting can take a while.

*EDIT* since the whole debugging setup required for flutter apps is run too.

If you want to run dart code only, consider creating a dart project without flutter.